# Is there any Kestrel gems out there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kestrel

I'm interested with [kestrel](http://github.com/robey/kestrel/), is there any rubygems or library for connecting kestrel with ruby/rails?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have my order correct: Kestrel is based on Starling, which used memcached as an interface. Therefore any of the memcached gems should work correctly to connect to Kestrel.

Answer (score 1):

There is also kestrel-client: https://github.com/twitter/kestrel-client